# After node creation how do i add simple buttons to edit the field values

Tags: commerce, hooks

``I'm new to drupal,I'm trying a create a content type with some field values which the user can use to create the content for the content type.In the node_view i have added some markup html to create additional generated fields to the content type.Now i want to add few buttons for the user to change the values in my content.

I created a form in node_view hook with a submit button so when user clicks the button i get to modify the node's properties,but i dont understand how to pass the node_id to callback form handler.

Or In general what's the standard process to let users create content for content type with server generating the additional info for the content.

```
function mymod_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
if ($node->type == 'app') 

$node->content['apikey'] = array(
        '#markup' => "<strong>Client Key</strong> <br/> ".$key['client_key'] ." <br/> <strong>Client Secret</strong> <br/>".$key['client_secret']."<br/> Node id". $node->nid.",",
        '#weight' => 10
    );

    $form = drupal_get_form('redirect_button_form');
    $node->content['redirect_button'] = $form;

function redirect_button_form($form, &$form_submit) {
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t('Reset Key'),
       // '#callback' => 'my_special_btn_function',
    );



  $form['nid'] = array(
    '#value' => arg(1),
    '#type' => 'hidden'
);
}

function redirect_button_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

$nid=$form_state['input']['nid'];

drupal_set_message('The form has been created nodeid,'. $node->nid .',key reset');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The $node_id is blank as there is no value passed for it. In order to get node_id in the submit handler function, you should pass the node_id in the form. So pass the node id value as a hidden field in the form and get the value of hidden form element through $form_state of *redirect_button_form_submit*. In that way you can do it.
   Example :
   $form['node_id'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => $nid);
2. Yes it is possible for you to edit $node->content['apikey'] if and only if it is saved in database. Create a new field as apikey in the content type and store it.
   Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much Vidhya,works perfectly,I caught the value with  arg(1),There was still a problem getting the nid since  '#value' => $nid as nid is not visible in the form definition.If it is visible may be i'm missing some concept.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to find the node nids.

1. You can get from the URL using **arg ()**  function 
   for example if the url is www.example.com/node/123645/
   arg (0) represents : node
   arg (1) represents : 123645
2. Through node object 
   always **$node->nid** gives you the node nid

Comment: as shown in the code the node_id gives me nothing it displays blank.Do you think the node id is propgated to the submit handler and also is it possible to edit $node->content['apikey'] since it is custom generated markup and not a content_type field.Im basically trying to reset the keys with the buttons